# Universal operator >> for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I just learned about overloading operators and decided to overload `operator >>` for `std::vector`. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but it works.

```
void operator >> (istream &in, vector<int> &_vector)
{
    int vectorSize;
    cout << "Enter vector size\n";
    cin >> vectorSize;

    _vector = vector<int>(vectorSize);

    cout << "Enter the array\n";
    for (int &element : _vector)
        in >> element;
}
```

But then I realized that this method works only for `vector<int>` and doesn't work for other vectors. How can I make it universal and work with any vector?

Comment: How much do you know about templates?

Comment: i know nothing about templates

Comment: Your extract function should not ask for the vector size, that makes it impossible to use for e.g. files. Instead you need to think of other ways to get the size (like storing it as a separate value first) or use some other way to delimit the contents of the vector data (like have it begin with `'{'` and end with `'}'`, and then parse the input).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i know that entering the size in that function is not a good thing to do. i just did it for the test. thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: In general, stream extractors should not prompt for input; they should just read from the stream. Leave the prompting to the caller, who knows better what the source of the input is, whether a prompt is needed, and what it should say.

Comment: You could pretend it is JSON or something similar. Clear the vector, extract a character which should be a start brace, extract one element, then get one character. If it is a comma, continue extracting elements. If a end brace, stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal changes:

```
template <class T>
void operator >> (istream &in, vector<T> &_vector)
{
    int vectorSize;
    cout << "Enter vector size\n";
    cin >> vectorSize;

    _vector = vector<T>(vectorSize);

    cout << "Enter the array\n";
    for (T &element : _vector)
        in >> element;
}
```

Note that there are many improvements you should do to the code: use `std::size_t`, use `std::vector::resize()`, avoid `std::cin/cout` inside an operator, avoid `using namespace std;`, return the appropriate type, avoid identifiers that start with `_` (even if valid here)... Plus the rest that they told you in the question comments, too.

Comment: thank you for helping me. i know about cin/cout inside the operator. it was just for the test. thank you for the other suggestions. im going to try to fix all the moments you said about

Comment: @MaximYarmolik You're welcome! (half a year late :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had some fun with this. Here's mine:

Source file json-style-vector-input.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T> &v) {
    std::string_view separator = "";
    constexpr std::string_view comma = ", ";
    os << '[';
    for(const auto &i: v) {
        os << separator;
        separator = comma;
        os << i;
    }
    os << ']';
    return os;
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T> &v) {
    char c;
    is >> c;
    if(c != '[') {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    v.clear();
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
        T tmp;
        is >> tmp;
        if(!is) return is;
        v.push_back(std::move(tmp));
        is >> c;
        if(!is) return is;
        if(c == ']') {
            done = true;
        } else if(c != ',') {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::ios::iostate &state) {
    using std::ios;
    if(state == ios::goodbit) os << "goodbit"sv;
    if((state & ios::badbit) == ios::badbit) os << "badbit"sv;
    if((state & ios::failbit) == ios::failbit) os << "failbit"sv;
    if((state & ios::eofbit) == ios::eofbit) os << "eofbit"sv;
    return os;
}

template<typename Ch = char>
class quoted_string : public std::basic_string<Ch> {
};

template<typename Ch>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, quoted_string<Ch> &s) {
    char c;
    is >> c;
    if(!is) return is;
    if(c != '"') {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    std::getline(is, s, '"');
    while(s.length() > 0 && s[ s.length()-1 ] == '\\') {
        s[ s.length()-1 ] = '"';
        std::basic_string<Ch> more;
        std::getline(is, more, '"');
        s += more;
    }
    return is;
}

template<typename Ch>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const quoted_string<Ch> &s) {
    os << '"';
    if( s.find('"') != std::basic_string<Ch>::npos ) {
        for( const auto& c: s ) {
            if( c == '"' ) os << '\\';
            os << c;
        }
    } else {
        os << static_cast<std::basic_string<Ch>>(s);
    }
    os << '"';
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::cin >> a;
    if(!std::cin) {
        std::cout << "input failure: "sv << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    std::vector<quoted_string<char>> b;
    std::cin >> b;
    if(!std::cin) {
        std::cout << "input failure: "sv << std::cin.rdstate() << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
    }
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build command (Linux):

```
g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -pthread -O3 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects  -std=c++17   -pthread  json-style-vector-input.cpp   -o json-style-vector-input
```

Test file test2.txt:

```
[1,99,2222]
["fred", "string with spaces", "", "another space string",
"string \"string\" string"]
```

Test command:

```
$ ./json-style-vector-input <test2.txt 
[1, 99, 2222]
["fred", "string with spaces", "", "another space string", "string \"string\" string"]
```